# MVC controller id with further actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So currently been trying to make a website (relatively new with MVC). Say I have the current link:

www.website.com/Project/3

Which works fine. However Inside that project, I am wanting the 3 to pretty much always be there to specify the project in a better manner (as people can have multiple projects). So if they go to a page inside the project I want it to look like so:

www.website.com/Project/3/CreateOption

I have been trying to think about a way to do it, but can't think of any nice way to do it. Done research but either can't figure out what to write into google, or it is impossible.

If anyone could help that would be awesome! If you need more information please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure your version of MVC.

But [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively easy to do.. *if* your url structure is very defined.  If you don't need standard default routing, then it's just as simple as doing this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Project",
   url: "Project/{projectId}/{action}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Project", action = "Index" }
```

This will require that the projectId be present.

Then, in your action method, you would have:

```
public ActionResult Index(int projectId)
{

}

public ActionResult CreateOption(int projectId)
{

}
```

The key here is that projectId is mandatory, and not optional, and that your route path is hard coded to Project.

You can default action to Index or whatever you like so that /Project/3 results in a default action, as shown above.  Or you can make the action mandatory as well.  If you need additional parameters, you can also add those as well if they need to be part of the url.

Comment: Is there any way to make a controller wide variable for the project id? It seems quite redundant and annoying to have to pass it in. Also what about for something like www.website.com/Project/3/EditOption/5.

Would it be just EditOption(int projectId, int optionId)

Comment: @Insight - You are forgetting that websites are stateless, and multi-user.  Certainly, there are ways avoid this.. you could store the "current" project id in the database for the users profile, and retrieve that on every call.. you could set a cookie that holds the current project id, etc.. And yes, as I said in my last paragraph "if you need additional parameters, you can also add those as well if they need to be part of the url", however you more or less have to make sure all optional parameters come at the end of the url, as optional params in the middle are hairy to deal with.